# NTEventLogAppender is not working for my Java Application

Tags: java, logging, log4j, event-log

I'm trying to write to the Windows Event Log and I have a nagging issue.

First I created the NTEventAppender using steps found here.
[How to create NTEventlogAppender.dll as required for logging event in the eventlog using log4cplus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697456/how-to-create-nteventlogappender-dll-as-required-for-logging-event-in-the-eventl)

I placed the .dll in the System32 folder.  When I built and ran the program in eclipse I received this error

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.log4j.nt.NTEventLogAppender.registerEventSource(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)I
    at org.apache.log4j.nt.NTEventLogAppender.registerEventSource(Native Method)
    at org.apache.log4j.nt.NTEventLogAppender.<init>(NTEventLogAppender.java:79)
    at org.apache.log4j.nt.NTEventLogAppender.<init>(NTEventLogAppender.java:49)
    at mahle.eolx.ws.Main.<clinit>(Main.java:30)
Exception in thread "main"
```

Do I need to do something differently since this is a Java application and the question linked above was for a C++ Application.

And if that is the case, what do I need to do.

EDIT:  I found out that I should be using the NTEventLogAppender.dll that was included with the log4j download, but I'm still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't get this to work, however I was able to log to the event viewer by using log4jna for the NTEventLogAppender (https://github.com/dblock/log4jna).

I took these steps

Download log4j and include the .jar file in your project http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/download.html

Download log4jna which is used to replace the NTEventLogAppender and add the necessary jars to your project (log4jna, jna, platform) http://log4jna.codeplex.com/

You will need to add the Win32EventLogAppender.dll somewhere in your application directory.

To get the logger to log meaningful messages you will need to change the registry

```
 Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

 [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\eventlog\Application\"YourAppNameHere"]
 "EventMessageFile"="C:\\Program Files\\"Your Application"\\Win32EventLogAppender.dll"
 "CategoryMessageFile"="C:\\Program Files\\"Your Application"\\Win32EventLogAppender.dll"
 "TypesSupported"=dword:00000007
 "CategoryCount"=dword:00000006
```